# Placing an image on a lat/lon point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, symbology

Can we place an image as a marker on a lat/lon point in QGIS using PyQGIS? Currently, I use `QgsVertexMarker()`... but I'd like an image on a point rather than a marker.

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()

canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()

m = QgsVertexMarker(canvas)

 m.setCenter(QgsPoint(float(lon),float(lat))

 m.setColor(QColor(255, 255, 0))

 m.setIconSize(10)

 m.setPenWidth(10)

m.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_X)
```

Answer (score 3):

Theory: Markers or Rubberbands as described in http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/de/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#rubber-bands-and-vertex-markers are not suitable for placing images on the map. I suggest embedding the images in svg containers and use svg marker symbols. Since the images might depend on attribute values, one might name the images according to the attribute values and set up an expression for **data defined override** (Button right beside the `...` button, expression > edit...) of the path to the svg file like

`'x:\\path\\to\\my\\svgs\\' || "the_attribute" || '.svg'`

[image]

resulting in

[image]

Be aware not to use too big image files, since this slows down QGIS significantly. The 8MP image used above makes QGIS nearly inoperable...

In PyQGIS you need to set up symbology for your layer as described in gorgeous detail in the PyQGIS Programming Cookbook: http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/de/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#appearance-symbology-of-vector-layers